# how can i use laravel csrf token on my nuxt vps

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I started creating a new application using **Laravel** and **Nuxt Js.**
i have two **VPS servers :**

1. The first one contain my **Nuxt JS ( Front End )**
2. The second one is the end **point ( back end ) based on Laravel**

i have created a lot of pages i insert the data correctly into my database. and now i tried to create a new function to update users data, but i get an error after submiting the form since i use the same axios code to insert.

Right now i'm working without tokens and i know its insecure way. 
i would like to know how can i communicate the tokens between **Nuxt JS** front end **Laravel** Backend.
i have two servers.

the error that i get is :

```
CSRF token mismatch.", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
```

this is my Axios code :

```
edit (customerId, submit = false) {
  this.editMode = true
  this.customerId = customerId
  if (submit === 1) {
    const formData = $('#add-customer').serialize()
    this.$axios.$post('/customer/update', formData).then((response) => {
      this.refresh = true
    })
  } else {
    this.$axios.$get('/customer/edit?customer=' + customerId).then((response) => {
      this.formFields = response.data[0]
    })
  }
}
```

when i change  this line from post to get, it works fine

```
this.$axios.$post('/customer/update', formData)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a single Redis server for session management,so you have a centralized location. or using a database, for more details check laravel doc

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session

Comment: what do you mean by using database

Comment: You can configure laravel to store session in the database https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#database-sessions so both servers will read from the same database and will have centralized session storage

Comment: nice idea, we suggest that i will create a third vps ( database server ). how my front end ( nuxt, vps server )  will read the database since . ( may be using node js ? )

Comment: the database server can be under one of the servers, you don't have to create a third server

Comment: don't forget to vote for the answer and mark it, please :)